# Escaping characters in a Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to escape the '@' in the below code for a Jenkins build:

```
            sh "curl --dH "@$Tom" http://google.com"
```

How do I escape it?

**Edit**: If I use a \ in front of the @ as displayed below:

```
            sh "curl --dH "\@$Tom" http://google.com"
```

I get another error, stating unexpected character "\".

Comment: Have you tried double slash ? like \\@ ?

Comment: @TristanDeoliveira Yes, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. no need to escape @ character instead of that you need to escape double quotes and $ mark

```
sh "curl --dH \"@\${Tom}\" http://google.com"
```

Update: if Tom is a variable,It can be inject into string like this `${Tom}`

jenkins pipeline syntax is groovy so you can try them with this online groovy ide

https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-groovy-online

Comment: Thank you, Why will this work? Isn't that escaping my whole variable though? As $Tom is a variable defined in the script earlier.
Just trying to gain a better understanding as I'm new to the whole Jenkins syntax.

Comment: @Who because there is a outer double quotes even if you escape from inner double quotes `\"@\${Tom}\"` it will elevated by outer double quotes which make whole thing is string.

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation and help it all makes sense to me now :)

Comment: This can be insecure if the variable can't be trusted: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Avoid double quotes around the Groovy string, since they can lead to security issues via [Injection via Interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation), if you can't guarantee the content of your variable is safe.

Instead, you can pass your variables in the shell's environment:

```
script {
    env.Tom = "Hello World";
}

sh 'curl --dH "@$Tom" http://google.com'  // $Tom is not interpolated by Groovy
```